# How to deal with nullable values in scala.js facades?

Tags: scala.js

I'm trying to write a Scalajs facade for the [request](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request) library which has a method using the callback pattern:

```js
request('http://www.google.com', function (error, response, body) {
  console.log('error:', error); // Print the error if one occurred
  console.log('statusCode:', response && response.statusCode); // Print the response status code if a response was received
  console.log('body:', body); // Print the HTML for the Google homepage.
});
```

In this pattern either `error` is null and `response` and `body` are defined or vice versa.

What's the best way to reflect this pattern in a ScalaJS facade? The best I could come up with is:

```js
@js.native
@JSImport("request", JSImport.Default)
object Request extends js.Object {
  def apply[A](uri: String,
               requestConfig: js.Object,
               callback: js.Function2[js.JavaScriptException, Response, A]): Unit = js.native
}
```

After executing the method I then use `Option` to match the correct case:

```js
Request(url, RequestConfig(queryString, headers), (error, response) => {
  (Option(error), Option(response)) match {
    case (Some(err), _) => // handle error
    case (_, Some(res)) => // handle success
    case (None, None) => // This will only happen if there is a bug in the request library
  }
})
```

I don't like this because 1) I have to write an unnecessary match for `(None, None)` or ignore the non-exhaustive match warning and 2) the facade doesn't accurately describe the types.

I have also tried using `js.UndefOr[js.JavaScriptException]` but this returns a `Some(null)` from `.toOption` and `js.JavaScriptException | Null` but I can only seem to convert this to a `Option[js.JavaScriptException | Null]`.

Comment: Maybe type your wrapper as `Either[JavaScriptException, Response]`? Also, I don't know the status of `Future` in Scala.js, but if possible, I would try to avoid callbacks and do `def apply(uri, config): Future[Response]` where in the case of an exception the Future would be failed. Then it becomes `Request(uri, config).map(response => turnIntoA)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unlike `undefined`, Scala.js does not give you special tools to deal with `null`.

This is because in Scala everything is nullable (many of us do not like this fact, including myself, but that's a different discussion).

Therefore, we must argue that the facade *does* accurately describe the types to the extent possible with the Scala / Scala.js type system.

If you need to use this often, a wrapper like @Thilo suggests is indeed your best option:

```scala
object RichRequest {
  def apply(uri: String, req: RequestConfig): Future[Response] = {
    val p = Promise[Response]()
    Request(uri, req, (error, response) => {
      if (error != null) p.failure(error)
      else p.success(response)
    })
    p.future
  }
}
```

Alternatively, if you want to keep the API callback based, consider using a `Try`.

Note that if you want to go down that path, consider using [request-promise-native](https://github.com/request/request-promise-native) where you get this out of the box (using JavaScript promises).

So your facade will become:

```
@js.native
@JSImport("request-promise-native", JSImport.Default)
object Request extends js.Object {
  def apply(uri: String, requestConfig: js.Object): js.Promise[Response] = js.native
}
```

And the call site:

```
Request(url, RequestConfig(...)).toFuture
```